Using structlog with Datadog
We're using the logging module from the stdlib to send logs from our Django app to Datadog and we have customised our logging based on django-datadog-logger
We're exploring a move to structlog, and I was wondering if there is a package that gives a good starting point to get log formatted for Datadog, similar to what the above library does as Datadog expects a few top level keys.
Has anyone built something reusable already? Is there a recipe that we could reuse?
PS: I already found the structlog Django extension, my question is more around formatting for Datadog

Do you need anything specific else than what DD is offering/documenting themselves: https://ddtrace.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations.html#structlog ?

Oh I didn't think of looking at ddtrace docs, but in insight, I should perhaps have started there. Thanks!
